# JavaScript on JSP with Spring form:select

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a jsp:

```
<form:select path="operation" onchange="myFunc(${oper.id})">
  <c:forEach items="${operList}" var="oper">
    <form:option label = "${oper.name}" value="${oper.id}|${oper.name}"/>...
```

And I have a js function `myFunc(id) { alert(id); }`
Then I change select value I see alert: undefined. 
Wat's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cant get the value `${oper.id}` outside the `<forEach>` loop , as it is a element in the list.

To get the selected value from the dropdown `onchange()` event , add the `id` attribute to the field and get it in the javascript

**jsp :**

```
<form:select id="mySelect" path="operation" onchange="myFunc()">
  <c:forEach items="${operList}" var="oper">
    <form:option label = "${oper.name}" value="${oper.id}|${oper.name}"/>...
```

**jquery:**

```
  function myFunc() {
    var  selectedValue= $("#mySelect").val();
    alert(selectedValue);
   }
```

And if you prefer to do it without jquery , here is the javascript version ,

```
    function myFunc() {
    var selectBox = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(selectedValue);
   }
```

or simply,

```
<form:select id="mySelect" path="operation" onchange="myFunc(value)">
      <c:forEach items="${operList}" var="oper">
        <form:option label = "${oper.name}" value="${oper.id}|${oper.name}"/>...
```

And in javascript,

```
function myFunc($val) {
        alert($val);
       }
```

passed the `value` attribute with the function call as the parameter.

hope this helps!!